# Websql not working on phonegap build

Tags: html, phonegap-build, web-sql

I am trying out basic sql operation on a phonegap but it displays a blank page.
The sql operations work properly on safari.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, log)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, log) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, log) VALUES (2, "logmsg")');
msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
});

db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;
msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
 msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log +"</b></p>";
 document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
}
}, null);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any issues with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var db = openDatabase('CBDB', '1.0','mySpecialDatabaseThatWontWork',10*1024*1024);

db.transaction(function (tx){
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cb');
alert("dropped table");
createDB();
queryDB();
},
function (tx, error) {
// error
alert('0.Something went wrong: '+ error.message);
});

function createDB(){
db.transaction(function (tx) {       
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cb (id unique, text)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO cb (id, text) VALUES (1, "myTest")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO cb (id, text) VALUES (2, "another")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO cb (id, text) VALUES (3, "andYetAnother")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO cb (id, text) VALUES (4, "ohAndAgain")');
    alert("DB success");  
    },
    function (tx, error) {
        // error
        alert('1.Something went wrong: '+ error.message);
    });
} 

function queryDB(){
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM cb',[], function (tx, results) {
        var rows = results.rows;
        alert(rows.length);
        for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            var x = rows.item(index);
            alert(x.text);
        } 
    },
    function (tx, error) {
    // error
    alert('2.Something went wrong: '+ error.message);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no success and error methods in your code.
Try this way, so that you can know where the error is:

```
db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);

function createDB(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, log)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, log) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, log) VALUES (2, "logmsg")');

      console.log("Table created");
}

function errorCB(tx, err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

function successCB() {
        console.log("DB success!");

}
```

Comment: Thanks.....but the thing is when i package it as phonegap app i cannot view the console messages..or is there any way we can view them?..it working properly on safari with no errors.

Comment: you need to add this plugin to get console messages:
"org.apache.cordova.console"